# Making barchart in R Programming using specific rows from csv file

Tags: r, csv, bar-chart

I want to create a barchart in R. Each bar should show each day of the week. Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun. 
My CSV file looks like this, I have 288 rows of data for each day of the week. I want to create bar chart on average of the third column, (it is called occupancy). Does anyone know how to create a barchart like this where I can specify certain rows instead of columns?

```
17/09/2018 00:00,00:02:26,37,47,146
17/09/2018 00:05,00:02:26,37,47,146
17/09/2018 00:10,00:02:26,37,47,146
17/09/2018 00:15,00:02:26,37,47,146

18/09/2018 00:00,00:03:34,26,20,214,0
18/09/2018 00:05,00:03:34,26,20,214,0
18/09/2018 00:10,00:00:28,5,0,28
18/09/2018 00:15,00:00:02,3,0,2
18/09/2018 00:20,00:00:01,3,0,1
```

Comment: Could you please provide a `dput` of your data after you import them into `R` via `read.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that I think does what you want.

```
## packages
library(lubridate) # for changing the dates to days of week
library(dplyr) # for reformatting the data
library(forcats) # for recoding factors
library(ggplot2) # for plotting

## import your data
dat <- data.frame(time = c("17/09/2018 00:00", "17/09/2018 00:05", "18/09/2018 00:00", "18/09/2018 00:05"),
              occupancy = c(37, 37, 26, 26))

## get average occupancy and add new variable with day of the week
dat.n <- dat %>%
  mutate(time = dmy_hm(time)) %>%
  mutate(month = month(time)) %>%
  mutate(day_month = mday(time)) %>%
  mutate(day_week = wday(time)) %>%
  group_by(month, day_month) %>%
  summarize(avg_occupancy = mean(occupancy), day_week = unique(day_week)) %>%
  mutate(day_week = fct_recode(as.factor(day_week), "Monday" = "2",
                           "Tuesday" = "3"))

## make barplot
ggplot(dat.n, aes(x = day_week, y = avg_occupancy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Average Occupancy")
```

[resulting barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ily9h.jpg)